# R lattice correctly labelling points with xyplot

Tags: r, plot, panel, lattice

```
library(lattice)

# load reproducible data set
attach(mtcars)

# change the rownames into a column value and remove the rownames
mtcars <- as.data.frame(cbind(car.name=rownames(mtcars), mtcars))
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL

# panel function parameters so that I label the points that are 100 units
# different between the hp and disp values and label the points with the car name

panel = function (x, y, ...) {
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    x1 <- x[x-y > 100 | y-x > 100]
    y1 <- y[x-y > 100 | y-x > 100]
    panel.text(x1, y1, labels=mtcars$car.name, pos=3)   
}

#calling the xyplot
xyplot(hp~disp, data=mtcars, main=NULL, ylab="hp", xlab="disp", 
       jitter=TRUE, pch=1, as.table=TRUE, panel=panel)
```

[image: xyplot of mtcars]

I can see that all points which show a difference of 100 units between `hp` and `disp` have a label.
However, the label does not match the actual data in the table.
I can tell this by first sorting `mtcars` by the column `disp` in descending order:

```
mtcars <- mtcars[order(-mtcars$disp),]
head(mtcars)
              car.name  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
15  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
16 Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
17   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
25    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
7           Duster 360 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

As you can see the `car.name` with the highest `disp` is the Cadillac Fleetwood and this is not labelled in the graph, in fact another car name appears.

How can I have the correct car name displayed according to my condition that only cars with >100 units difference between `disp` and `hp` are labelled? Something is wrong with my panel function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x1`, `y1` and `mtcars$carname` have different lengths, hence the labels do not correspond:

```
length(x1)=11
length(y1)=11,
length(mtcars$carname)=32
```

Here is a modified version:

```
panel = function (x, y, ...) {
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    v <- abs(x - y) > 100
    panel.text(x[v], y[v], labels=mtcars$car.name[v], pos=3)
}

xyplot(hp~disp, data=mtcars, main=NULL, ylab="hp", xlab="disp", 
       jitter=TRUE, pch=1, as.table=TRUE, panel=panel)
```

[image]

Comment: The changes made by rcs indeed gives the right names to the the specific points on the xyplot.  I have also made the relevant change to my real data and the plot is as how I expect.